# ng-serve Typescrypt compiling issue with symbolic linked modules

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack

Currently I am working on a web project that consists for a server side and a client side. Some of the model files are defined on the server side which I would want to reuse on the client side.

So I performed the following:

```
cd server
npm link
cd ../client
npm link ../server
```

But when I try to transpile  using ng-serve my TS on the client I am getting the following:

```
ERROR in ../Server/source/models/hardware.ts
Module build failed: Error: C:\Users\naaht\Documents\Dev\Server\source\models\hardware.ts is missing
from the TypeScript compilation. Please make sure it is in your tsconfig via the 'files' or 'include' property.
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: when you do a symlink, the relative path from that linked directory will always be from the original location.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9807
Its actually an issue in angular-cli that has a work around.

Answer (score 0):

The compilation is almost entirely driven by `tsconfig.json`, you can check the section `files` inside and then trace back why `hardware.ts` is missing.

Comment: It seems like there is nothing wrong with the compilation, because if I do a tsc build the output is fine. What I think is wrong is when webpack compiles, which I think perhaps there is something to do with the symbolic linking?